# extract values from printlog file , getting user and pagecount from a specific printer

Tags: powershell, active-directory, network-printers

is there a easy way to get per user the total pages they have printed on a specific printer.
and put them in a text or csv file?
The printserver have a windows 2008 32 bits Os. in a 2008 AD enviroment

regards

Dennis

Answer (score 1):

This is really easy to get the value for each computer, by using the performance counter cmdlets built into PowerShell V2.  It's less easy to match these values to a set of users, but active directory should be a lot of help.

Get-Counter will get counter values, and list counters that exist.  This one liner gives you all print queue counters:

```
Get-Counter -ListSet "*print*" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Paths
```

To see how many pages this computer has printed, use:

```
Get-Counter '\Print Queue(*)\Total Pages Printed'
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This solution don't gives me the total per user.. on a specific printer , only the total pages printed , or Jobs